# Vuejs track input field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to check whether my input field is empty or not.

## Logic

1. if `form.name` has value, use increase function
2. if `form.name` is empty, use decrease function
3. do not use `increase`, `decrease` functions on each character that user inputs or removes

## Code

```
<el-form-item label="Product name *">
  <el-input v-model="form.name"></el-input>
</el-form-item>


methods: {
 increase() {
  this.percentage += 8.3;
  if (this.percentage > 100) {
    this.percentage = 100;
  }
 },
 decrease() {
  this.percentage -= 8.3;
  if (this.percentage < 0) {
    this.percentage = 0;
  }
 },
}
```

**any idea?**

## Update

`Script`

```
data() {
    return {
        form: {
            name: '', // require
            slug: '',
            price: '', // require
            supplier_id: '', // require
            new_price: '',
            base_price: '',
            sku: '',
            qty: 1, // require
            active: '', // require
            photo: '',
            photos: [],
            shortDesc: '',
            longDesc: '',
            origin: '',
            tags: [],
            brand_id: '', // require
            categories: [],
            user_id: '',
            seoTitle: '',
            seoTags: '',
            seoPhoto: '',
            seoDescription: '',
            variations: [],
            options: [],
            condition: '', // require
            isbn: '',
            ean: '',
            upc: '',
            height: '',
            weight: '',
            lenght: '',
            width: '', // require
        },
    }
},
methods: {
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/api/admin/products/store', this.form)
        .then(res => {
            // do my things
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    },
}
```

`HTML`

```
<el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="120px" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    // my inputs (listed in form part in script above)

    <el-button type="primary" @click="onSubmit" native-type="submit">Create</el-button>
</el-form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use `@focus` and `@blur` events to check if `form.name` has a value before increasing or decreasing, this would be fired on focus or on blur events, so you will not have the methods fired on each character input or deletion.

for example:

```
<el-form-item label="Product name *">
  <el-input @focus="checkName" @blur="checkName" v-model="form.name"></el-input>
</el-form-item>


methods: {

 checkName() {
   //If form.name has a value then run increase method, otherwise run decrease method
  !!this.form.name ? this.increase() : this.decrease()
 },
 increase() {
  this.percentage += 8.3;
  if (this.percentage > 100) {
    this.percentage = 100;
  }
 },
 decrease() {
  this.percentage -= 8.3;
  if (this.percentage < 0) {
    this.percentage = 0;
  }
 },
}
```

You can see a working fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/7ye651rn/)

**UPDATE**

Alright so i did follow the rules you state on your question, and i didn't know you wanted to get the percentage of completion of the form, so in order to do that, i would suggest to use a computed property, you can read more about computed properties in the [VueJS Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), this way the percentage is calculated based on the criteria we can give it, and only if the form has values.

```
computed: {
        formProgress: function () {
        let totalInputs = Object.keys(this.form).length;
        let filledInputs = 0;
        Object.values(this.form).forEach(val => {
          if (!!val){
            filledInputs++;
          }
        });
        return (filledInputs/totalInputs)*100
        }
    },
```

As you can see in one single computed property you can handle the complex logic and return the value reactively, to explain it better, i'm counting the lenght of the form object, to get total number of inputs in your form, so it's important to have all your form data inside the form data object, then i convert that object to an array to iterate it, and i check if each property has a value on it, if does it, i add 1 to the `filledInputs` counter, and finally just return a simple math to get the percentage. please check the new Fiddle here to see it in action:

[FORM PROGRESS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2wbtd618/)

If you have any other doubt just let me know.

**UPDATE 2:**

All right in order to only count for specific inputs for the form progress, i have modified the code to work based on an array that contains the names of the properties that are required. here is the full code:

```
data() {
      return {
        form: {
            name: '',
          lastName: null,
          categories: [{}],
        },
        requiredFields: ['name', 'categories']
      };
    },
    computed: {
        formProgress: function () {
        let totalInputs = this.requiredFields.length;
        let filledInputs = 0;
        Object.entries(this.form).forEach(entry => {
            const [key, val] = entry;
          if (this.requiredFields.includes(key)){
            switch (val.constructor.name) {
                case "Array":
                if (val.length !== 0){
                    if (Object.keys(val[0]).length !== 0){
                    filledInputs++;
                    }
                }
                break
              case "Object":
                if (Object.keys(val).length !== 0){
                    filledInputs++;
                }
                break
              default:
                if (!!val){
                    filledInputs++;
                }
            }
          }
        });
        return Number((filledInputs/totalInputs)*100).toFixed(1)
        }
    },
```

And here is the updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xqzbpoLh/4/)

As you can see now i'm using Object.entries to get the key and value of the form object, so you can have a single form object to send to your backend, this way i'm checking first if the key is in the required fields, and if has a value, so all you need to do is update the `requiredFields` data array with the same names as your inputs data property to make the validation work, also there is a validation depending if is array, array of objects, or object, that way it will validate input on each data type.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but this increased the value each time i focus on input regardless of i placing value to that input or not. the idea behind this increase/decrease is to let user know how many percent of the form s/he has filled (probably you've seen such forms before)

Comment: @mafortis you didn’t say anything about what you wanted to accomplish with your question and I followed your rules, check my answer update, now it works for your requirements.

Comment: thank you so much, Ive just checked fiddle and it was working nicely, however the reason that i was trying to specific form inputs such as `form.name` was because i only need to do this math for my require inputs not all inputs in my form. let say my form has 20 inputs but only 3 of them are required, so this percentage 0 to 100 is only for those 3 inputs. is there a way to specity them in your code?

Comment: @mafortis you could simply have 2 form data objects, so you can compute only over the one that contains the required inputs, and other for the rest of inputs.

Comment: then i would have send 2 different type of data to process in backend right?

Comment: is that possible we make array of my desire inputs and use that array instead of `this.form`?

Comment: @mafortis not at all, if you are sending the data with a Form Data object you can simply add both to the request.

Comment: Yes you can create an array with your desired inputs, but that way you’ll have to do update that array each time you may want to add a new required input, the way I did it will count over the property length that the object has

Comment: ok give me 5 min to turn on my system and I'll share the code. in the meanwhile about my latest comment would it work like this? `let array1 = [this.form.name, this.form.xyz]`

Comment: @mafortis updated answer to work with required inputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217873/discussion-between-laravdev-and-mafortis).